# How to get last element of an array in smarty templates

Tags: smarty

I want to get last element of array in smarty template without using loop

```
<?php
$arr = array("first","second","third");

$smarty->assign("arr",$arr);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is an easy way to get this done within your Smarty template code using a [variable modifier](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifiers.tpl):

```
{$arr|@end}
```

Since all php-functions can be used as modifiers ,  [`end`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) will do the job just fine.