# How to get the last element from an array in Smarty

Tags: php, smarty

I'm trying to retreive the last array from an smarty array.

Here is a sample of the array.

```
Array (2)
0 => Array (3)
  id => "1"
  name => "John"
  age => "25"
1 => Array (3)
  id => "2"
  name => "Doe"
  age => "16"
```

I have tried the following method  [How to get last element of an array in smarty templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36889268/how-to-get-last-element-of-an-array-in-smarty-templates) but it doesn't work for my case.

I tried `{$array|@end}` and `{$array.id|@end}`

How I retreive normally `{$array[1].id|@end}` but this is not stable. I would like to avoid using `foreach` loop

Comment: What does `{$array|@end}` return? It seems like it would return what you need, the last element of the array, in this case `['id' => '2', 'name' => 'Doe', 'age' => 16]` could you add what that expression returns to your question?

Comment: do you have the loop, or just need last element of an array? And specify pls the version of smarty

Comment: @RaulSauco it returns me exactly `Array`

Comment: @V-K I just need the last element of an array

Comment: Guess it isn't very `smart`-y

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   end($array)
```

Reference https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.end.php

Comment: This is not smarty

Answer (score 0):

you can give this a try if it help you

```
{foreach from=$array key=myId item=i name=foo}
  {if $smarty.foreach.foo.last}
      <p>This is the last item from the array!</p>
  {/if}
{/foreach}
```

Comment: How do I print the id for example ? I tried `{$foo.id}`